# Testing React Native Image.getSize: Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; string given

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-hooks-testing-library

I have a hook that detects the orientation of a React Native Image:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'

const useFindImageSize = (image) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await Image.getSize(image,
        (width, height) => {
          setWidth(width)
          setHeight(height)
        })
    })()
  }, [image])

  return { width, height }
}
```

And have written a test initially to see if `getSize` has been called:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useFindImageSize from '../useFindImageSize'

describe('useFindImageSize', () => {
  const getSize = jest.spyOn(
    Image, 'getSize').mockImplementation(jest.fn()
  )

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })

  it('should call getSize', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      useFindImageSize('test_image')
    )
    expect(getSize).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

A basic test which I would've thought would work, (this is based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69060487/the-current-result-of-a-custom-hook-is-updated-when-testing-using-react-hooks-te) about the same topic).

But I'm getting this error when running my test:

```
 ● ImageOrientation › useFindImageSize › encountered a declaration exception
Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; string given
```

Which refers to `const getSizeSpyOn = jest.spyOn(`

The hook takes an image uri as its argument and then decides whether it should be a portrait or landscape image, but I'm pretty stuck on how to get around this. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
const getSize = jest.spyOn(Image.prototype, 'getSize')
  .mockImplementation(jest.fn())
```

> Same as your code, with just "`.prototype`" added (without quotes).

Comment: Thanks for responding! Unfortunately that came back with `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`.